# What is the correct the first or the second?

Tags: jquery, ajax, each

What is the correct the first or the second ? Both are working, but what is the correct one ?
Is there a better way ?

```
$(function() {$.getJSON('./index_logg2.php', null, pro1);});
function pro1(data) {$.each(data.crop, function() {port=data.crop[0].id_user; port1=data.crop});
if (port1[0]) {$('#port_emp').remove();
   $('#my_user1').html('<a href=rock.php?user='+ port +'><img src="j3nUh9_oiN_3ks/user_pics'+ port +'/ thumb_ '+ port1[0].pic_name +'" title="View profile" ></a>').fadeIn(700);
   $('#del_user').html('<img src="images/delconv.png" title=Delete >'); }}
```

OR

```
$(function() {$.getJSON('./index_logg2.php', null, pro1);});
function pro1(data) {$.each(data.crop, function() {port=data.crop[0].id_user; port1=data.crop;
if (port1[0]) {$('#port_emp').remove();
   $('#my_user1').html('<a href=rock.php?user='+ port +'><img src="j3nUh9_oiN_3ks/user_pics'+ port +'/ thumb_ '+ port1[0].pic_name +'" title="View profile" ></a>').fadeIn(700);
   $('#del_user').html('<img src="images/delconv.png" title=Delete >'); })}}
```

Comment: I can't see the difference

Comment: which part of the code is different from both?

Comment: yeah same here..both looks same for me :(

Comment: And please, learn to indent the code

Comment: they do different things. the first does the if block after the each. the second not only does the if block at each iteration, it also includes the last 2 lines in the if block. the code could not possibly be formatted in a way that is more difficult to read.

Answer (score 1):

If they are both working, then the first one is better because it only runs the `if` statement once, whereas the second one runs the `if` statement on each iteration of the `.each` loop.